# sqlite ON CONFLICT difference between ABORT and FAIL

Tags: sqlite, conflict

From http://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html

> ABORT
>   When an applicable constraint violation occurs, the ABORT resolution algorithm aborts the current SQL statement with an SQLITE_CONSTRAIT error and backs out any changes made by the current SQL statement; but changes caused by prior SQL statements within the same transaction are preserved and the transaction remains active. This is the default behavior and the behavior proscribed the SQL standard.
>
> FAIL
>   When an applicable constraint violation occurs, the FAIL resolution algorithm aborts the current SQL statement with an SQLITE_CONSTRAINT error. But the FAIL resolution does not back out prior changes of the SQL statement that failed nor does it end the transaction. For example, if an UPDATE statement encountered a constraint violation on the 100th row that it attempts to update, then the first 99 row changes are preserved but changes to rows 100 and beyond never occur.

Both preserve changes made before the statement that caused constraint violation and do not end transaction. So, I suppose the only difference is that FAIL resolution does not let further changes to be made, while ABORT does only back up only conflicting statement. Did I get right?

Comment: Your interpretation does not match the docs pasted here.  ABORT: rolls back the entire sql statement but does not affect other sql's in the same txn.  FAIL: only prevents the specific failing row (and subsequent ones in the same SQL statement) - but allows other rows to be changed. FAIL and ABORT both allow other statements within the same  txn to proceeed.

Comment: in addition, the term "transaction" in the documentation means a BEGIN TRANSACTION, COMMIT block I believe

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The answer is simple: FAIL does not rollback changes done by the current statement.

Consider those 2 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS constFAIL (num UNIQUE ON CONFLICT FAIL);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS constABORT (num UNIQUE ON CONFLICT ABORT);
INSERT INTO constFAIL VALUES (1),(3),(4),(5);
INSERT INTO constABORT VALUES (1),(3),(4),(5);
```

The statement

```
UPDATE constABORT SET num=num+1 WHERE num<5
```

will fail and change nothing.
But this satement

```
UPDATE constFAIL SET num=num+1 WHERE num<5
```

will update the first row, then fail and leave the 1 row updated, so the new values are 2, 3, 4, 5

Comment: Could end values at **5** to make it even more succinct. Beautiful demonstration!