# Android Sqlite SQLiteAbortException does not work

Tags: android, sqlite

My application uses some complex sql statements so I've gotten in the probably bad habit of using execsql often, even when I could/should probably use something like insert or update for simple things(below).

However, I am wondering why this is not working

```
String query = "UPDATE OR ABORT " + myTable + " SET " + .... column names and values + WHERE ...
try {
    db.execSQL(query);
} catch (SQLiteAbortException e) {
    Log.i(TAG, "error in the update");
```

I've tried this with data that should clearly fail (ie, there is no matching record to update) but I am not hitting the catch.  Initially I had used UPDATE OR FAIL and a SQLiteConstraintException but when that was not caught I tried the SQLiteAbortException which specifically states

> An exception that indicates that the SQLite program was aborted. This
>   can happen either through a call to ABORT in a trigger, or as the
>   result of using the ABORT conflict clause.

What am I missing here?

Update: just adding [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11370712/sqlite-on-conflict-difference-between-abort-and-fail) for reference on INSERT/UPDATE OR ABORT/FAIL   If SQLiteAbortException is not the way, how to catch an update abort/fail?

Comment: I was thinking, `ABORT` is only a resolution in case of constraint violations. If data is not there to update, then there's also no violation to abort. Could you try an update statement that would violate a constraint (such as updating a primary key value with another already existing one)?

Comment: @Nobu  SQliteAbortException does not work as expected.   So I tried with an INSERT rather than update where I knew I would get a violation due to non-unique key.  No effect.  However, changing to SQLiteConstraintException did throw the error.   Using UPDATE in both cases does not throw an error, though you would not expect a constraint violation error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried to find an explanation for that behavior in the Java source code part of Android API level 19, but the only place where `SQLiteAbortException` is (re-)thrown is in a static helper class named `DatabaseUtils`. It gets originally thrown from native code using a method in [`android_database_SQLiteCommon.cpp`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/9a7debe5857ffc7c71cfc4082b1b6d72a5cf81cd/core/jni/android_database_SQLiteCommon.cpp). It is thrown when SQLite returned error code 4, which is named `SQLITE_ABORT` and [documented as](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_abort.html):

> /* Callback routine requested an abort */

I strongly assume a C callback function is meant with that. You can register callbacks with SQLite and they seem to have some level of control. So it appears to me that error code which gets translated into an `SQLiteAbortException` has little to do with an SQL `ABORT` clause. in fact, I highly doubt that that exception ever gets thrown, since I don't think that the native part of Android's SQLite database driver hooks callbacks into SQLite that abort requests.

The [SQLite documentation of `ABORT`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html) is also specific which kind of error code to expect:

> **ABORT**
>
> When an applicable constraint violation occurs, the `ABORT` resolution algorithm aborts 
>   the current SQL statement with an *`SQLITE_CONSTRAINT` error* (...snip)

So according to the documentation of SQLite and what the native Android source code actually does, the `SQLiteConstraintException` is to be expected in that case and apparently Android's documentation of `SQLiteAbortException` is not entirely correct.

Comment: Thanks for digging through all of that!  I'll put a report in re SQLiteAbortException and link this thread.  Clearly there was also my misunderstanding (or too high expectation) that a failure to update would also cause SQLite to branch into the fail or abort clause. That does not appear to be the case and I guess the only way to see if an update has failed is to check on number of rows changed.